# Save the terminal history to a file for print

Tags: command-line, history

My Ubuntu headless server is about to lose both hard drives(raid1). I already saved the most important stuff. Now I'm sitting in front of a Mac OS X client with the terminal open (ssh).

I need to save the whole or at least the most important install commands I wrote. So basically the first 1k commands...

I would like to print that & save it to a file. So I can easily reinstall everything.

By the way, also save some hard researched config files that I don't remember where they are.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

There is already a *hidden* file in your home directory called `.bash_history` which you can print it. One observation here: this file, in a default configuration, doesn't contain the commands used in your current opened terminal session. So, close the terminal before to print it.

But if you want to save the terminal history in another file, then you can use the following command (this new file will contain also and the commands used in your currently opened terminal session):

```
history > history_for_print.txt
```

A new file called `history_for_print.txt` will be created in your *currently working directory* containing your last used commands (by default HISTSIZE=1000 and HISTFILESIZE=2000, but you can change these values in your `~/.bashrc` file).

Comment: You can also run "history -a" to write commands from the current session to the history file without having to exit.

Answer (score 4):

To save your code outputs which display in command window you can use
for example
./ABC.sh &> output.txt
This command save all outputs include errors and esults into text file

Comment: This is not what the question was about. Read the question and accepted answer.

Comment: It is a related and useful answer. The goal of SO is to be a useful resource.

Comment: daghighan......